# Flyway customizing 'version' in naming convention

Tags: sql, flyway

I'm using Flyway 3.2.1. Current properties are set to:

```
flyway.sqlMigrationPrefix=V
flyway.sqlMigrationSuffix=.sql
flyway.initVersion=0000
flyway.outOfOrder=false
```

According to the [documentation](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/), **version** can be:

```
Dots or underscores separate the parts, you can use as many parts as you like
```

[image]

Therefore I came up with this `V_201509071234_Filename.sql`, even according to  [examples](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/), my name above should be valid. However when attempting to execute, it complains:

> Flyway Error: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid version
>   containing non-numeric characters. Only 0..9 and . are allowed.
>   Invalid version: .201509071234

However, if I were to add a number before first underscore, like so,  `V2_201509071234_Filename.sql`, it works.

How can I force Flyway to accept `V_201509071234_Filename.sql` as a valid name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the prefix the be V_ and the separator to be _ and it should be OK (I hope)

Comment: hi @alex, after running flyway:info i run flyway:validate to validate scripts. But It fails to validate, error is, "Validate failed. Detected resolved migration not applied to database". But if i remove flyway:validate it works just fine. Any idea why?

Comment: At the error message says, the migration in question has not been executed yet. Set target to current or run migrate first and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

This name would conform to the flyway convention: V201509071234_Filename.sql (no underscore in between V and the version number).