# Flyway Exception for invalid characters in the version

Tags: maven, flyway

I am trying to integrate Flyway with my simple maven project for learning purposes.

I am using the following plugin and configuration:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.9</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://${database.host}:${database.port}/${database.schema}?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8</url>
                    <user>${database.user}</user>
                    <password>${database.password}</password>
                    <sqlMigrationPrefix>V_</sqlMigrationPrefix>
                    <sqlMigrationSeparator>__</sqlMigrationSeparator>
                    <locations>
                        <location>filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migrations</location>
                    </locations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And this is the name of my sample migration sql:

```
V_1__create_new_table.sql
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I keep getting the following exception:

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid version containing non-numeric characters. Only 0..9 and . are allowed. Invalid version: V.1
```

I did refer to the following question and as you can see in the configuration, I have done what has been asked:
[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954572/flyway-customizing-version-in-naming-convention)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply try defining only `V` as your migration prefix, and naming your migration file `V1__Create_New_Table.sql` (these are Flyway defaults).

The way you defined `V_` as your prefix and `V_1__Create_New_Table.sql` as the file name is what's causing the trouble, because this tells Flyway that this migration is of version `V.1`, which is incorrect of course.

For smaller number of versions, you can go for something like this: `V1_1__Create_New_Table.sql` which will give you migration version of `1.1` for instance.

In the related SO answer you provided, the suggested answer was to use `V_` as a prefix and `_` as a separator, while you have defined in your plugin config `__` as a plugin separator.

Comment: @NLabrahmi I see the issue now. Thanks a lot.